# Cutting an SVG Mask into an image

Tags: css, svg, clipping, image-masking, image-clipping

I'm having a problem with a new website I'm developing. It's the first time I'm using SVG's. Basicly I need to cut a circle that is always centered in the page out of my image to show the image under the element. I have tried working with my clipping and everything was great. I can't seem to find the error in my mask code. Here's the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gkdq96do/3/) to a quick fiddle that I setup. Thanks!

```
    <div class="bg-gradient">
    <img src="http://www.redhdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/red-background-6.jpg"/>
</div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" fill="none" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

A mask with fill="none" is no mask at all. Try fill="white" instead.

If you want a hole then you'll want to make your mask the inverse of what it is now so use a path with [`fill-rule: evenodd`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty) property and first trace out a rectangle using M, h and v round the edge of the image and then trace out a circle using arcs or bezier curves in the opposite direction to the direction you traced the edge so that the fill-rule makes a hole in the path.

You'd be better off switching back to a clipPath though since it uses far less memory than a mask if all you want to do is clip.

Comment: but I need to cut a hole into the element in order to see the background that is under it.

Comment: Ok, so I decided to take another approach and use an SVG and fill the background with an image. The problem I'm facing now is that I want to have the background-image/pattern fixed. So that when scrolling it would show different parts of the image. This is what I created atm. http://www.dev.badalic.com/skrollr-test.html